# Run Time Error - (pics)

Tags: c++, runtime

I've been testing my C++ server application recently, and when a few clients are connected and doing a variety of things, I've been getting the odd run time error which crashes the server. Could you help me - how do I debug the following error when all I have is these event viewer logs:

[image: Event Viewer Results]

The type of error was "C++ Server has stopped responding", with just an option to close the dialogue box. I couldn't even see the console.

Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide.

Thanks.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/aa657bbd-5548-48e2-b3d2-2f3c772f5e62/ says Fault Bucket `...is generated by Watson error reporting framework, but there should be an event log entry just before that which describes what application failed and at what address.`  So apperently that doesn't help

Comment: What is the message in the little scroll box?  Could that have hints? (No idea, just poking my nose in)

Comment: I have no idea. But, you're right there was some "Watson" error message...I updated it. Notice the "compare" mention...how do I find that memory address?

Comment: `0xc0000005` is an access violation. You probably are trying to work an invalid pointer.

Comment: Is it possible to find the specific area where that might have occured based off this information? edit: Hmm, no that Watson error was from yesterday...not today when this error occurred. The is no other information from today.

Comment: Can't you attach a debugger to the service process, wait for the crash and see where it occurs? Also, if Dr Watson prepared a minidump you could use WinDbg or Visual Studio to inspect the status of the process at the moment of the crash.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend two courses of action for you to take:

1) Add sufficient logging (to a file or standard out) so that you can trace where the problem is coming from.

2) Run your server in a debugger so that you can pinpoint the location and type of the fault. This will give you a call stack and index to your source files if set up correctly

I can recommend [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009) as a standalone debugger for the task, though I would assume that you are using an IDE with debugging capability.

If for some reason you can't run the server in a debugger, then you can at least attach one when the error occurs. So instead of Dr Watson giving you information WinDbg can attach to the process giving you a call stack and all the other goodness.

Comment: I will definitely look into finding a standalone debugger. I haven't used one before.

Answer (score 1):

Configure WER (Windows Error Reporting) on the server to save crash dumps of your crashing apps to the disk. Then load and inspect them in WinDbg. Don't forget to set the app's symbols file (.pdb) in the debugger to see the stacks and variables.